# macd demo - adding ADX indicator

Tags: r, quantstrat

I am trying to add ADX threshold signals to the macd demo. Doing so, results in the following error. I have mucked around with traceback() but fail to understand what is amiss. Any pointers would be highly appreciated. Thank You!

the error is produced by the last command in the below code:

ERROR:

```
Error in inherits(x, "xts") : Argument "HLC" missing (without default value)
Additional: Warning:
In applyIndicators(strategy = strategy, mktdata = mktdata, parameters = parameters,  : some arguments stored for ADX do not match
```

CODE:

```
# Set initial Dates
initDate <- "2000-01-01"
endDate <- "2012-09-01"
# Set initial Equity
initEq <- 100000

# Pull Yahoo Finance data
symbols <- c("TFM")
getSymbols(symbols, from=initDate, to=endDate, index.class=c("POSIXt","POSIXct"))

# adjust for splits/dividends (comment to replicate blotter example)
TFM <- adjustOHLC(TFM, use.Adjusted=TRUE)

# set currency
for(symbol in symbols) {
  stock(symbol, currency="USD", multiplier=1)
}

# Delete (1) portfolio, (2) account, and (3) order book if they already exist
suppressWarnings(rm("account.macd","portfolio.macd",pos=.blotter))
suppressWarnings(rm("order_book.macd",pos=.strategy))

# Initialize new/blank (1) portfolio, (2) account, and (3) order book
initPortf("macd", symbols=symbols, initDate=initDate)
initAcct("macd", portfolios="macd", initDate=initDate, initEq=initEq)
initOrders(portfolio="macd", initDate=initDate)

# Initialize a strategy object
stratMACD <- strategy("macd")

# Add the MACD indicator to the strategy
stratMACD <- add.indicator(strategy=stratMACD, name="MACD",arguments=list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata))))

# Add the ADX indicator to the strategy
stratMACD <- add.indicator(strategy=stratMACD, name="ADX", arguments=list(x=quote(HLC(mktdata))))

# There are two MACD crossover signals:
# (1) MACD crosses Signal from below
stratMACD <- add.signal(stratMACD, name="sigCrossover", arguments=list(columns=c("macd","signal"), relationship="gt"), label="MACD.gt.SIG")

# (2) MACD crosses Signal from above
stratMACD <- add.signal(stratMACD, name="sigCrossover", arguments=list(columns=c("macd","signal"), relationship="lt"), label="MACD.lt.SIG")

# There are two ADX threshold (30) signals
stratMACD <- add.signal(stratMACD, name="sigThreshold", arguments=list(column="ADX",relationship="gt",threshold=30,cross=TRUE), label="ADX.gt.30")
stratMACD <- add.signal(stratMACD, name="sigThreshold", arguments=list(column="ADX",relationship="lt",threshold=30,cross=TRUE), label="ADX.lt.30")

# There are two rules:
# (1) buy when MACD crosses above the SIGNAL -AND- ADX > 30
stratMACD <- add.rule(stratMACD, name="ruleSignal", arguments=list(sigcol="MACD.gt.SIG", sigval=TRUE, orderqty=1000, ordertype="market", orderside="long", pricemethod="market", TxnFees=-5, osFUN=osMaxPos), type="enter", path.dep=TRUE)
stratMACD <- add.rule(stratMACD, name="ruleSignal", arguments=list(sigcol="ADX.gt.30", sigval=TRUE, orderqty=1000, ordertype="market", orderside="long", pricemethod="market", TxnFees=-5, osFUN=osMaxPos), type="enter", path.dep=TRUE)
# (2) sell when MACD crosses below the SIGNAL -AND- ADX < 30
stratMACD <- add.rule(stratMACD, name="ruleSignal", arguments=list(sigcol="MACD.lt.SIG", sigval=TRUE, orderqty="all", ordertype="market", orderside="long", pricemethod="market", TxnFees=-5), type="exit", path.dep=TRUE)
stratMACD <- add.rule(stratMACD, name="ruleSignal", arguments=list(sigcol="ADX.lt.30", sigval=TRUE, orderqty="all", ordertype="market", orderside="long", pricemethod="market", TxnFees=-5), type="exit", path.dep=TRUE)

# Set position limits so we don't add to the position every month Close > SMA10
addPosLimit(portfolio="macd", symbol="TFM", timestamp=initDate, maxpos=1000, minpos=0)

# Process the indicators and generate trades
out <- try(applyStrategy(strategy=stratMACD, portfolios="macd"))
```

Comment: solved (but cannot 'answer' my question yet):after a few more hours of searching finally found the culprit. ADX requires

    ADX(HLC=quote(HLC(mktdata))

instead of

    ADX(x=quote(HLC(mktdata))

oh man ... ;-)